# Prove that $[(p \to q) ∧ (q \to r)] \to (p \to r)$ is a tautology without truth tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove that this tautology is always true without truth table.
 $\begin{align}
[(p \to q) ∧ (q \to r)] \to (p \to r)
\end{align}$

What mistake did I make? It doesn't seem to be true.

$\begin{align}
[(p \to q) ∧ (q \to r)] \to (p \to r)
\\ [ (\neg p \vee q) ∧ (\neg q \vee r)] \to (\neg p \vee r)
\\ [(p ∧ \neg q) \vee (q∧\neg r)] \vee (\neg p \vee r)]
\\ [\neg p \vee(p∧ \neg q)] \vee [ r \vee (q ∧ \neg r)]
\\ [(\neg p \vee p) ∧(\neg p \vee \neg q)] \vee [(r \vee q) ∧ ( r \vee \neg r)]
\\ [1 ∧ (\neg p \vee \neg q)] \vee [1 ∧(r \vee q)]
\\ (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee (r \vee q)
\end{align}$

Comment: What relation does the sequence of formulas at the end of the question have to each other, and to your question? Much more prose is needed before your question is readable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From line 3 to line 4 looks like associativity and commutativity to me; from $(a \lor b) \lor (c \lor d)$ to $(c \lor a) \lor (d \lor b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you have a disjunction of four terms. Just use associativity and commutativity to rearrange them in a way that produces tautology.

Notice that if you did not have to specify the order of operations
(and you shouldn't really have to, since disjunction is associative),
you could have written the last line
$$\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r \lor q.$$

Comment: However, I end up with $ \neg p \vee r $. It's supposed to be 1, isn't it?

Comment: @NamNguyen $a \vee \neg q \vee q$ is 1 no matter what $a$ is.

Comment: Oh. That's silly of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$[(p \to q)\land(q \to r)]\to(p \to r)$

1. $p$ Assumption
2. $\neg r$ Assumption
3. $q \to r$ Premise
4. $\neg q$ modus tollens 2,3
5. $p \to q$ Premise
6. $ \neg p$ modus tollens 4,5
7. $p \land\neg p$ conjunction 1, 6,
8. Contadition
9. $p \to r$  contradiction method 1, 2, 8.